# NotImplementedError: pbkdf2_hmac() function is unimplemented on this machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

I am working on upgrading ruby and rails version to my app. I was using rails 3.2, and ruby '1.9.3', For this version `Gibberish` works fine on heroku. After I upgraded rails 4.2 and ruby 2.2.0, Gibberish not working and through an error on `heroku`.

So I created a new app in heroku and configured 4.2 and 2.2.0 and then tested. There Gibberish works fine without any error. But I don't like to  configured new app. Because I have well configured on my existing app. Is there any point did I missed? Here the trace...

```
irb(main):002:0> Gibberish::AES.new("12345").encrypt("data")
NotImplementedError: pbkdf2_hmac() function is unimplemented on this machine
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/gibberish-2.0.0/lib/gibberish/aes.rb:140:in `pbkdf2_hmac'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/gibberish-2.0.0/lib/gibberish/aes.rb:140:in `encrypt'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/gibberish-2.0.0/lib/gibberish/aes.rb:100:in `encrypt'
from (irb):2
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in `start'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
from bin/rails:10:in `require'
from bin/rails:10:in `<main>'
```

Note: I am working latest version on `Gibberish`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See if [this issue](https://github.com/mdp/gibberish/issues/23) will help. tl;dr: try Ruby 2.2.2.

Comment: Yeah valid point. But how my new app with rails 4.2 and ruby 2.2.0 works fine?

Comment: A new app with Rails 4.2, Ruby 2.2.0 and Gibberish gem? Works fine? Report that in the linked issue then, it's important information.

Comment: Yeah okay sure... But now I have two app. Both app was configured with rails 4.2 and 2.2.0, One of the app works fine and but not another even I am using latest Gibberish version on both app.

Comment: ...and you're not using latest Ruby on both. The gem author claims that his gem works on Heroku with Ruby 2.2.2.

Comment: Really I accept your point. But then how it could be working on my new app with ruby 2.2.0.

Comment: There may be many factors. Some different dependencies, different features in use. For the former you could start inspecting `Gemfile.lock`s for relevant differences, for the latter... well, if the test code is identical in both, I have no idea.

Comment: Yeah Gemfile.lock may solve. Will check that both app. Any way , thanks a lot... :)

Comment: No problem. Just don't forget to update the question if you find something relevant. And feel free to flag/delete comments as obsolete, once they are.

Answer (score 0):

`Prior to Gibberish 2.0, the default encryption mode was CBC. But now not!.`

I have come up the solution after verifying the format of the encryption. Now Gibberish is working based on OpenSSL version. Gibberish 2 will works in latest version on OpenSSl. If you want to work with old version of ssl then you can must `CBC`.

```
Gibberish::AES::CBC.new("12345").encrypt("data")
```

Gibberish 1.4 will generate

```
Gibberish::AES.new("p4ssw0rd").enc("Some top secret data")
#=> U2FsdGVkX187oKRbgDkUcMKaFfB5RsXQj/X4mc8X3lsUVgwb4+S55LQo6f6N\nIDMX
```

but now CBC will generate this formatted output.

I recommend to update openssl in heroku.